# Uploading pdf and certificate using multer and sign pdf but there is error

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Erro is:**

> Error: Could not find ByteRange placeholder: /ByteRange [0 /********** /********** /**********]
>       at SignPdf.sign (E:\Personal\Projects\pdf-sign-node\node_modules\node-signpdf\dist\signpdf.js:53:13)
>       at app.post (E:\Personal\Projects\pdf-sign-node\app.js:25:28)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Personal\Projects\pdf-sign-node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (E:\Personal\Projects\pdf-sign-node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Immediate. (E:\Personal\Projects\pdf-sign-node\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:53:37)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:706:11)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
>       at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)

**Here is my code:**

```
const fs = require('fs');

const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const signer = require('node-signpdf').default;

const app = express();

const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, `./uploads`);
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    let fileName = file.originalname.split(' ').join('-');
    cb(null, Date.now().toString() + '-' + fileName);
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: fileStorage });

app.post('/pdf/sign', upload.fields([{ name: 'pdf' }, { name: 'certificate' }]), (req, res) => {
  const pdf = req.files.pdf[0].path;
  const certificate = req.files.certificate[0].path;

  const signedPdf = signer.sign(
    fs.readFileSync(pdf),
    fs.readFileSync(certificate)
  );

  fs.writeFileSync(`${__dirname}/upload/${req.files.pdf[0].filename}-signed`, signedPdf);

  res.status(200).json({
    message: 'success',
  });
});

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Appliction is listening on ${port}`));
```

Comment: check this issue, it might help: https://github.com/vbuch/node-signpdf/issues/7

Comment: It worked but on single pdf it is not working after appending signature it showing emtpy and working on multi page pdf any solution